# Can't import snapshot: Missing protocol (PsDELPH1xsx)

Tags: node

I'm on macOS Catalina. I'm attempting to import a snapshot. It will import all of the data, but when cleaning up I encounter an error and the import doesn't finish.

```
./tezos-node snapshot import ~/Downloads/tezos-mainnet-1241456.rolling --block BLsaxAwwd4hd6JD4z2fauE1JfrLRUM8Fa6j2MUM6wJK5imWytSf
Dec  3 21:28:58 - snapshot: Importing data from snapshot file ~/Downloads/tezos-mainnet-1241456.rolling
Dec  3 21:28:58 - snapshot: Retrieving and validating data. This can take a while, please bear with us
Context: 6539K elements, 531MiB read
Store: 0K elements, 531MiB read
Computing predecessors table 0K elements
Dec  3 21:32:50 - snapshot: Setting current head to block BLsaxAwwd4hd6JD4z2fauE1JfrLRUM8Fa6j2MUM6wJK5imWytSf
Dec  3 21:32:50 - node.main: Cleaning directory /Users/grant/.tezos-node because of failure
tezos-node: Error:
              Missing protocol (PsDELPH1Kxsx) when validating the block BLsaxAwwd4hd.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the branch of tezos of which I did a build. Branch `mainnet` isn't on delphi, apparently. Switching to the `latest-release` branch and rebuilding solves the issue.